# Regular Expression in python doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on the exercise in the book *Python for Informatics* which asks me to write a program to simulate the operation of the grep command on UNIX. However, my code doesn't work. Here I simplified my code and only intend to calculate how many lines start with the word 'Find'. I'm quite confused and wish you could cast light on it.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

fhand = urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt')
sumFind = 0

for line in fhand:
    line = str(line) #convert from byte to string for re operation
    if re.search('^From',line) is not None:
        sumFind+=1

print(f'There are {sumFind} lines that match.')
```

The output of the script is

> There are 0 lines that match.

And here is the link of the input text:
[text](http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt)

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the mistake is to convert bytes to string using `str`.

```
>>> str(b'foo')
"b'foo'"
```

You would have needed

```
line = line.decode()
```

But the best way is to pass a bytes regex to the regex, that is supported:

```
for line in fhand:
    if re.search(b'^From',line) is not None:
        sumFind+=1
```

now I get 54 matches.

note that you could simplify the whole loop to:

```
sum_find = sum(bool(re.match(b'From',line)) for line in fhand)
```

- `re.match` replaces the need to use `^` with search
- no need for loop, `sum` counts the times where `re.match` returns a truthy value (explicitly converted to `bool` so it can sum 0 or 1)

or even simpler without regex:

```
sum_find = sum(line.startswith(b"From") for line in fhand)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the shell reports:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    if re.match(b'^From',line):
  File "D:\Python3\lib\re.py", line 172, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object

Comment: either decode bytes or use byte pattern. Really, drop the loop and use `sum`

Comment: Adopt the bool method and it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is that the urllib module returns bytes instead of strings from the url/text file.

You can either:

1. Use bytes in your regex search: re.search(b'From', line).
2. Use requests module to download file as string and split by lines:

   import requests

   txt = requests.get('http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt').text.split('\n')

   for line in txt:
   ...